# Custom plugin development get help context to work in WP 4.3

Tags: contextual-help

I am stuck with the help tab for a custom plugin. In the past i used

```
   //ADD HELP INFO
// add_action('contextual_help', array($this, 'my_plugin_help'));
```

and now i am trying to convert the plugin help part with

```
    add_action('load-' .CUSTOM_POST_TYPE, 'my_plugin_add_help');
    function my_plugin_add_help() {

        wp_die('it works!');
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        //
        $screen->add_help_tab(array(
            'id' => CUSTOM_POST_TYPE,
            'title' => 'Plugin help',
            'content' => 'help content'));       
    }
```

But the help tab isn't shown? Any tips?

[edit]
I realise I am working in a class so here's a bit of the class

```
    class Participant{

    public function __construct() {
add_action('load-' .CUSTOM_POST_TYPE, 'my_plugin_add_help');
.......
}

    function my_plugin_add_help() {

        wp_die('it works!');
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        //
        $screen->add_help_tab(array(
            'id' => CUSTOM_POST_TYPE,
            'title' => 'Plugin help',
            'content' => 'help content'));       
    }
```

, but still I don't have the right hook. I have tested with

```
add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'my_plugin_add_help'));
```

[EDIT 2] Workable Solution

```
    class MyClass {


        public function __construct() {


            add_action('admin_head' , array($this, 'my_plugin_add_help'));
    ......
    }

     public function my_plugin_add_help() {

            $screen = get_current_screen();
            //print_r($screen);

            if($screen->post_type == CUSTOM_POST_TYPE){//make it only visible on custom plugin page
            $screen->add_help_tab(array(
                'id' => CUSTOM_POST_TYPE,
                'title' => 'Help title',
                'content' => 'help content'));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: `CUSTOM_POST_TYPE` is a very generic name for a declaration/constant, have you verified your hook is actually running? e.g if you put wp_die("it works!"); at the top of the function, do you see a white screen with "it works!"? Have you verified you're using the correct hook at the right time for `get_current_screen` to function?

Comment: no i am not using CUSTOM_POST_NAME but define('PARTICIPANTS_2016', 'Summer-2016') going to check my function when i am behind my Mac again

Comment: @TomJNowell i am glad you mention to put wp_die("it works!") for testing. I realise i am working in a class so i had to call array($this, 'my_plugin_add_help'), but still i don't have the right hook

Comment: Please properly format your post and add **all** relevant code. You say it is a class, how and where do you initialize it

Comment: I'd follow the code backwards, putting breakpoints or `wp_die` calls in the constructor, then the place your class is called until it shows on the frontend, then start bugfixing from there on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is this:

```
add_action('load-' .CUSTOM_POST_TYPE, 'my_plugin_add_help');
```

While your hunch that you need to put `array( $this, 'my_plugin_add_help' )` because it's inside a class is correct, the root of the problem is that the hook you're trying to attach it to is never called, and isn't a part of standard WordPress.

Instead, try hooking on to `init`, or better yet, `admin_init` ( help tabs only appear in the admin area ):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'my_plugin_add_help' ) );
```

Comment: hmm, i tried admin_init but i notice get_current_screen() is null as it stated in https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen and i need it to add the help screen, right? I will try to find a later hook

Comment: Ok found a workable hook admin_head ;) tx